# Javascript getting value from dump

Tags: javascript

I currently trying to do the sort nested function that i refer from here [Sort Nested](http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/)

I'm trying to get the value from the on click function. I had try to alert the "arrerid" but it output like this:

```
'0' ...
        'item_id' ...
        'parent_id' => "none"
        'depth' => "0"
        'left' => "1"
        'right' => "22"
    '1' ...
        'item_id' => "4"
        'parent_id' ...
        'depth' => "1"
        'left' => "2"
        'right' => "3"
    '2' ...
        'item_id' => "1"
        'parent_id' ...
        'depth' => "1"
        'left' => "4"
        'right' => "9"
    '3' ...
        'item_id' => "2"
        'parent_id' => "1"
        'depth' => "2"
        'left' => "5"
        'right' => "8"
```

How can i get the value of 'item_id' and the array value ? Because i wanted to get the value to be inserted into database with php. Please guide me. Thanks

Here are the html code i currently have :

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- =================================================================================================================== -->
<html lang="en">

<!-- =================================================================================================================== -->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>nestedSortable jQuery Plugin</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Demo page of the nestedSortable jQuery Plugin">
    <meta name="author" content="Manuele J Sarfatti">


    <style type="text/css">

        html {
            background-color: #eee;
        }

        body {
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
               -moz-border-radius: 10px;
                    border-radius: 10px;
            color: #444;
            background-color: #fff;
            font-size: 13px;
            font-family: Freesans, sans-serif;
            padding: 2em 4em;
            width: 860px;
            margin: 15px auto;
            box-shadow:             1px 1px 8px #444;
            -mox-box-shadow:        1px 1px 8px #444;
            -webkit-box-shadow:     1px -1px 8px #444;
        }

        a, a:visited {
            color: #4183C4;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        pre, code {
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        pre {
            width: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        small {
            font-size: 90%;
        }

        small code {
            font-size: 11px;
        }

        .placeholder {
            outline: 1px dashed #4183C4;
            /*-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
            -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            margin: -1px;*/
        }

        .mjs-nestedSortable-error {
            background: #fbe3e4;
            border-color: transparent;
        }

        ol {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            padding-left: 30px;
        }

        ol.sortable, ol.sortable ol {
            margin: 0 0 0 25px;
            padding: 0;
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        ol.sortable {
            margin: 4em 0;
        }

        .sortable li {
            margin: 5px 0 0 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .sortable li div  {
            border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
            -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
            -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            border-color: #D4D4D4 #D4D4D4 #BCBCBC;
            padding: 6px;
            margin: 0;
            cursor: move;
            background: #f6f6f6;
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f6 47%, #ededed 100%);
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(47%,#f6f6f6), color-stop(100%,#ededed));
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%);
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%);
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%);
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#ededed 100%);
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed',GradientType=0 );
        }

        .sortable li.mjs-nestedSortable-branch div {
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f6 47%, #f0ece9 100%);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#f0ece9 100%);

        }

        .sortable li.mjs-nestedSortable-leaf div {
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #f6f6f6 47%, #bcccbc 100%);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#f6f6f6 47%,#bcccbc 100%);

        }

        li.mjs-nestedSortable-collapsed.mjs-nestedSortable-hovering div {
            border-color: #999;
            background: #fafafa;
        }

        .disclose {
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 10px;
            display: none;
        }

        .sortable li.mjs-nestedSortable-collapsed > ol {
            display: none;
        }

        .sortable li.mjs-nestedSortable-branch > div > .disclose {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .sortable li.mjs-nestedSortable-collapsed > div > .disclose > span:before {
            content: '+ ';
        }

        .sortable li.mjs-nestedSortable-expanded > div > .disclose > span:before {
            content: '- ';
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 2em;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        h2 {
            font-size: 1.2em;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: italic;
            margin-top: .2em;
            margin-bottom: 1.5em;
        }

        h3 {
            font-size: 1em;
            margin: 1em 0 .3em;;
        }

        p, ol, ul, pre, form {
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 1em;
        }

        dl {
            margin: 0;
        }

        dd {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0 0 0 1.5em;
        }

        code {
            background: #e5e5e5;
        }

        input {
            vertical-align: text-bottom;
        }

        .notice {
            color: #c33;
        }

    </style>


<!-- =================================================================================================================== -->
<body>

<header>
    <h1>nestedSortable jQuery Plugin</h1>
    <h2>2.0</h2>
</header>

<section>
    <p>
        This is the demo page for the nestedSortable jQuery plugin.
    <p>
        <strong>Follow the development, read the docs and download the latest version directly from the 
        <a href="https://github.com/mjsarfatti/nestedSortable">GitHub page</a>.</strong>
    </p>
</section> <!-- END section -->

<section id="demo">
    <ol class="sortable">
        <li id="list_1"><div><span class="disclose"><span></span></span>Item 1</div>
            <ol>
                <li id="list_2"><div><span class="disclose"><span></span></span>Sub Item 1.1</div>
                    <ol>
                        <li id="list_3"><div><span class="disclose"><span></span></span>Sub Item 1.2</div>
                    </ol>
            </ol>
        <li id="list_4"><div><span class="disclose"><span></span></span>Item 2</div>
        <li id="list_5"><div><span class="disclose"><span></span></span>Item 3</div>
            <ol>
                <li id="list_6" class="mjs-nestedSortable-no-nesting"><div><span class="disclose"><span></span></span>Sub Item 3.1 (no nesting)</div>
                <li id="list_7"><div><span class="disclose"><span></span></span>Sub Item 3.2</div>
                    <ol>
                        <li id="list_8"><div><span class="disclose"><span></span></span>Sub Item 3.2.1</div>
                    </ol>
            </ol>
        <li id="list_9"><div><span class="disclose"><span></span></span>Item 4</div>
        <li id="list_10"><div><span class="disclose"><span></span></span>Item 5</div>
    </ol>

    <h3>Try the custom methods:</h3>

    <p><br />
        <input type="submit" name="serialize" id="serialize" value="Serialize" />
    <pre id="serializeOutput"></pre>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="toArray" id="toArray" value="To array" />
    <pre id="toArrayOutput"></pre>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="toHierarchy" id="toHierarchy" value="To hierarchy" />
    <pre id="toHierarchyOutput"></pre>
    <p>
        <em>Note: This demo has the <code>maxLevels</code> option set to '3'.</em>
    </p>
</section> <!-- END #demo -->


<section id="license">
    <h4>License</h4>
    <p>
        This work is licensed under the MIT License.<br>
        Which means you can do pretty much whatever you want with it.
    <p>
        Nonetheless if this plugin saved you money, saved you time or saved your life please take a moment to think about the work I've been doing for you and consider sharing a bit of your joy with me. Your donation, however small, will be greatly appreciated.<br>
        Thank you.
    </p>

    <!-- Paypal Donate Button -->
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="RSJEW3N9PRMYY">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="nestedSortable">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="002">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF:btn_donate_SM.gif:NonHosted">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-640-20110306-1/en_GB/i/btn/btn_donate_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online.">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-640-20110306-1/it_IT/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    <!--<a href="/">contact me</a>-->
    </form>
    <!-- END Paypal Donate Button -->

    <p>
        © 2010&ndash;2015 Manuele J Sarfatti
    </p>
</section> <!-- END #documentation -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mjs.nestedSortable.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable({
            forcePlaceholderSize: true,
            handle: 'div',
            helper: 'clone',
            items: 'li',
            opacity: .6,
            placeholder: 'placeholder',
            revert: 250,
            tabSize: 25,
            tolerance: 'pointer',
            toleranceElement: '> div',
            maxLevels: 3,

            isTree: true,
            expandOnHover: 700,
            startCollapsed: true
        });

        $('.disclose').on('click', function() {
            $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('mjs-nestedSortable-collapsed').toggleClass('mjs-nestedSortable-expanded');
        })

        $('#serialize').click(function(){
            serialized = $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable('serialize');
            $('#serializeOutput').text(serialized+'\n\n');
        })

        $('#toHierarchy').click(function(e){
            hiered = $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable('toHierarchy', {startDepthCount: 0});
            hiered = dump(hiered);
            (typeof($('#toHierarchyOutput')[0].textContent) != 'undefined') ?
            $('#toHierarchyOutput')[0].textContent = hiered : $('#toHierarchyOutput')[0].innerText = hiered;
        })

        $('#toArray').click(function(e){
            arraied = $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable('toArray', {startDepthCount: 0});
            arraied = dump(arraied);
            (typeof($('#toArrayOutput')[0].textContent) != 'undefined') ?
            $('#toArrayOutput')[0].textContent = arraied : $('#toArrayOutput')[0].innerText = arraied;
            alert("id:"+arraied);
        })

    });

    function dump(arr,level) {
        var dumped_text = "";
        if(!level) level = 0;

        //The padding given at the beginning of the line.
        var level_padding = "";
        for(var j=0;j<level+1;j++) level_padding += "    ";

        if(typeof(arr) == 'object') { //Array/Hashes/Objects
            for(var item in arr) {
                var value = arr[item];

                if(typeof(value) == 'object') { //If it is an array,
                    dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "' ...\n";
                    dumped_text += dump(value,level+1);
                } else {
                    dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "' => \"" + value + "\"\n";
                }
            }
        } else { //Strings/Chars/Numbers etc.
            dumped_text = "===>"+arr+"<===("+typeof(arr)+")";
        }
        return dumped_text;
    }

</script>

<!-- Piwik -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var pkBaseURL = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://mjsarfatti.com/piwik/" : "http://mjsarfatti.com/piwik/");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + pkBaseURL + "piwik.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script><script type="text/javascript">
try {
var piwikTracker = Piwik.getTracker(pkBaseURL + "piwik.php", 1);
piwikTracker.trackPageView();
piwikTracker.enableLinkTracking();
} catch( err ) {}
</script><noscript><p><img src="http://mjsarfatti.com/piwik/piwik.php?idsite=1" style="border:0" alt="" /></p></noscript>
<!-- End Piwik Tracking Code -->
```

Comment: i would like to help you, but please attach working codepen to make it easier for me

Comment: @KaterinaTort Hi, may i know what kind of codepen i can share with you in order to let u understand more easier@@?

Comment: @KaterinaTort May i explain more detail about my problem in discussion chat? Thanks

Comment: you'd better google what is codepen and provide link to yours, with comments in code

Comment: It's okay i had resolve my problem. Thanks